# Spring Integration DefaultFtpSessionFactory timeout parameters details

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration, apache-commons-net

I am configuring a ftpClientFactory using `org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory`.

I noticed it has 3 timeout related parameters. `connectTimeout`, `defaultTimeout` and `dataTimeout`.

I was reading [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-session-factory) but I could not find the exactly details about those properties.
I am guessing that the `dataTimeout` is a timeout for sending the file. `connectTimeout` is for establishing a connection with the FTP server. And the `defaultTimeout` is for both???

I could not find a place to check if my understanding is correct. Does anyone knows where to find it or can anyone confirm it to me based on experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connectTimeout` ends in `timeout` argument of [`Socket.connect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect-java.net.SocketAddress-int-) of both control and data connection.

`defaultTimeout` ends in [`Socket.setSoTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) of the control connection.

`dataTimeout` ends in `Socket.setSoTimeout` of the data connection.

Comment: For anybody like me wondering what is **data** and **control** connection:
FTP uses two parallel TCP connections to transfer a file, a control connection and a data connection. 

The control connection is used for sending control information between the two hosts -- such as user identification, password, commands to change remote directory, and commands to "put" and "get" files. 

The data connection is used to actually send a file. ([source](https://userpages.umbc.edu/~dgorin1/451/OSI7/dcomm/ftp.htm#:~:text=The%20control%20connection%20is%20used,to%20actually%20send%20a%20file.))