# What is the meaning of different timeout properties of Apache FTPClient (and DefaultFtpSessionFactory in Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration, apache-commons

There are following timeout properties used for FTP communication:

- **connectTimeout**: connection timeout in milliseconds, which will be passed to the Socket object's connect() method
- **defaultTimeout**: default timeout in milliseconds to use when opening a socket
- **dataTimeout**: timeout in milliseconds to use when reading from the data connection

Could you explain to Java/Kotlin developer why to set them and what bad things could happen if you do not set them?

To add some context: My server app needs to connect to FTP and list/upload/download/delete files. I would like to be sure my attempts to connect or transfer file won't hang forever in case something goes wrong.

Comment: See [Spring Integration DefaultFtpSessionFactory timeout parameters details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135741/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those properties from the `AbstractFtpSessionFactory` are propagated down to an `FTPClient`:

```
    if (this.connectTimeout != null) {
        client.setConnectTimeout(this.connectTimeout);
    }
    if (this.defaultTimeout != null) {
        client.setDefaultTimeout(this.defaultTimeout);
    }
    if (this.dataTimeout != null) {
        client.setDataTimeout(this.dataTimeout);
    }
```

The `connectTimeout` over there has a default value as `private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 60000;`. So, it is OK to miss it. Yes, this one is used when we create a `Socket` via `connect()`: `_socket_.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);`

The `defaultTimeout` is propagated down to `_socket_.setSoTimeout(_timeout_);` which has an effect on socket read operations. See `Socket.setSoTimeout()` JavaDocs. Yes, its default value is `0`. So, also OK to miss its configuration.

The `dataTimeout` is used for the server `Socket` created in a `ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE` for similar `setSoTimeout()` option. Default is the same: 0 - infinite wait for read operation answer.

I derived all of that from Apache Commons Net source code.

Doesn't look like the project provides some docs on the matter by itself: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

So, yeah, a rule of thumb: always configure those props with a reasonable values.

Comment: In case you use Apache Commons Net 3.7.2 or older [DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT is 0](https://github.com/apache/commons-net/blob/rel/commons-net-3.7.2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.java#L102) (meaning infinite).
Also applies for Spring Integration FTP version 5.4.x.